# after_filter :foo foo runs before controller in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I must be doing something wrong here. I want to a function to run after the controller has run. This function populates some part of my session variable and then i use that information in the next request. Here is the code.

```
class SummariesController < ApplicationController  
    after_filter :foo, :only=>[:bar]  

    def foo  
        session[:x] = y  
    end  

    def bar  
        #some code  
    end  
end
```

In this code `foo` gets called before `bar`. I want it to be called after bar is rendered. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`after_filter` executes before the response is sent to the client, so you wouldn't be able to run this after `bar` is rendered. From the Rails Guides:

> they have access to the response data that’s *about to be sent* to the client

Comment: Thanks for solving the confusion. However is there anyway to execute a method after bar is rendered?

Comment: This looks like it might be helpful, even though it's for an older version of Rails: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325538/rails-2-3-x-execute-code-after-request-was-rendered-and-returned